# Rails Model Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am attempting to create an association between a user and a list of trees. But for this app, the client cares if the trees are associated with either their yard or neighborhood.

So for example - if they go to create in their "yard"  a pine tree  elm tree 
and in the "neighborhood" pine tree and palm tree.

I want to have a single pine tree element but I want to call something like - user.yard_trees and tree.neighborhood_trees  -

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :yard_trees, class_name: 'Tree', foreign_key: 'yard_id'
  has_many :neighborhood_trees, class_name: 'Tree', foreign_key: 'neighborhood_id'
end

class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :yard, class_name: 'User'
end
```

This should work as intended if your tables are set up right. But that seems weird to me. If I were you, I would actually create Yard and Neighborhood Models and set it up this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :yard
  has_one :neighborhood
end

class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :yards
  has_and_belongs_to_many :neighborhoods
end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trees
  belongs_to :user
end

class Yard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trees
  belongs_to :user
end
```

EDIT:

`has_and_belongs_to_many` might fit better. That way you can have one pine tree object and associate it with many yards and neighborhoods.